# При замене контента, оставаться в том же месте

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть кнопка подгрузки товаров. Специфика в том, что приходит весь набор товаров, а не только новые. Поэтому для вставки применяется конструкция

```
    $(".goods-content").html(data);
```

В опере экран при добавлении остается на месте, а вот в хроме прокручивается (поднимается) вверх. Как исправить (остаться в том же месте)?

Comment: Запоминай положение скролла и при добавлении  изменяй с помощью `$(window).scrollTop();`. А вообще врёшь. Я проверя- в хроме не прокручивается

Comment: с такой формулировкой заголовка можно редиректить на форум философов)

Comment: Всё эфемерно, в одну и ту же воду дважды не вступить..

Comment: Подозреваю, что перед обновлением данных, ты их очищаешь. Не надо так.

Comment: Нет, очистка не происходит

Comment: Могу дать сайт для примера, на котором этот баг был замечен.

Answer (score 1):

В моем случае проблема была в том, что на сервере используется гугл оптимизация pagespeed. После ее отключения проблема исчезла.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запомнить высоту блока, потом вернуть первоначальное значение:

```
$(".goods-content").css({height:$(".goods-content").height()});
$(".goods-content").html(data);
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".goods-content").css({height:'auto'};
},1000)
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. Данные не обновляются